# Incorrect Intent State Resolution In Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have 2 intents in 2 different states.
TriviaState.AnswerIntent and StartState.ChooseQuizIntent.
Both intents accept a required slot type of AMAZON.Number

```
{
    "name": "AnswerIntent",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "answernum",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "samples": [
                "number {answernum}",
                "answer number {answernum}",
                "{answernum}",
                "answer {answernum}"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samples": [
        "number {answernum}",
        "answer {answernum}",
        "{answernum}",
        "answer number {answernum}"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "ChooseQuizIntent",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "quiznumber",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "samples": [
                "quiz {quiznumber}",
                "{quiznumber}",
                "quiz number {quiznumber}",
                "{quiznumber} please",
                "number {quiznumber}",
                "number {quiznumber} please"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samples": [
        "{quiznumber}",
        "quiz number {quiznumber}",
        "number {quiznumber}",
        "I'd like to play number {quiznumber}",
        "{quiznumber} please",
        "number {quiznumber} please",
        "quiz {quiznumber}"
    ]
},
```

When in StartState, if the user says 'number 2', StartState.ChooseQuizIntent is called correctly. However, if the user says '2', alexa maps this to the TriviaState.AnswerIntent which results in StartState.unhandled being called.
Conversely, when in the TriviaState, if the user says '2', TriviaState.AnswerIntent is correctly called but if the user says 'number 2', alexa maps it to StartState.ChooseQuizIntent which results in TriviaState.unhandled being called.
I realise both slots are receiving identical inputs from alexa's point of view but I thought that the states would be respected which they clearly are not.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same sample phrases to trigger the two different intents.

Comment: @Genfood My understanding is that state resolution would help find the correct intent. If both intents were in the same state, then fair enough, I could understand the problem but these are defined in different states. To require all intents to have different sample utterances seems crazy. If one intent is called when answering a question and one is called when selecting from another list for example, and both require the user to say 'number two' etc, as long as they are in different states of the application, I can't see why that doesn't work.

Comment: I also have the same problem... How you soved.

Comment: @Ash Which sdk version are you using? I found that, after moving to sdk v2, I had no more problems. State resolution is handled completely differently

Comment: @WJDev alexa-sdk 1.0.25 and this.handle.state not able change state

Comment: @WJDev can you please provide me the ref link... or sample example... I am fully new in alexa... i developed basic example but i want to manage state level...